# With NPOI, set Word paragraph to Heading 1 style

Tags: npoi

When using [NPOI](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI) to create a Word document, how does one set a paragraph to the built-in "Heading 1" style?

Here is what I have tried in F#:

```fs
let doc = XWPFDocument()
let p = doc.CreateParagraph()
p.Style <- "Heading 1"
let r = p.CreateRun()
r.SetText("Hello, world")
```

When I open the generated file in Word, the line "Hello, world" is not in the Heading 1 style.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is what I did:**

1. Using Word,

   - Create a new Blank document.
   - Include a paragraph that has the style(s) of interest.
   - Save the document to your project folder.
2. In code using NPOI,

   - Load the blank document.
   - Delete the contents of the document.
   - Write to your document, setting the paragraph style with the `styleId`.

**Here is an example:**

[image]

```fs
use fsSrc = new FileStream("blank.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
let doc = XWPFDocument(fsSrc)
while doc.RemoveBodyElement(0) do ()
let p = doc.CreateParagraph()
p.Style <- "Heading1"
let r = p.CreateRun()
r.SetText("Hello, world")
```

**Today I learned...**

1. The default styles are not included when creating a new `XWPFDocument()`.
2. The styles are identified by their `styleId`, not their user friendly names. The `styleId` for "Heading 1" is `Heading1`.